# SOAP UI - Save HTTP request to a GZIP file

Tags: http, groovy, soapui

I m using Soap UI free version for some rest mocking.

I need to persist my HTTP POST request (request received already compressed gzip) to a gzip file.
I have tried different ways to do that,  however after to execute the code, when I try to decompress manually the file I have the following error: "The archive is either in unknown format or damaged".

The HTTP POST request has the following header:

```
Host : 127.0.0.1:8091
Content-Length : 636
User-Agent : Java/1.7.0_07
Connection : keep-alive
Content-Type : application/octet-stream
Accept : text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*
Pragma : no-cache
Cache-Control : no-cache
```

Below the solutions that I have tried:

Solution#1:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  
byte[] data = mockRequest.getRequestContent().getBytes();  
def path="myfile.gz";  
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));  
bos.write(data);  
bos.flush();  
bos.close();
```

Solution#2

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
byte[] data = mockRequest.getRawRequestData();
def path="myfile.gz";
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));
bos.write(data);
bos.flush();
bos.close();
```

Can someone please help and let me know why I cannot decompress the gzip file and how I can do that?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you confirmed the data in getRawRequestData() is in fact gzip content? If not, try using curl to ensure that is the case. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538104/save-response-body-to-file-from-curl-request

Comment: Hi, if I change the content-type in the http post request to "gzip" i can see the message. However, I cannot change the content type, I need to find a solution with the content type = application/octet-stream.

Answer (score 1):

This is Groovy, so you don't need all this Java clutter.

Here's some code that might work:

```
new File( path) << mockRequest.rawRequestData
```

**EDIT**

Ok, based on your comments, for zip files to be copied correctly, you probably need something a little different:

```
import java.nio.file.*

Files.copy(new ByteArrayInputStream(mockRequest.requestContent.bytes), 
           Paths.get( 'destination.zip' ) )
```

Tested this with an actual zip file's byte[] as source and it worked. If it does not work for you, then the byte array you're getting from `requestContent.bytes` just isn't a zip file.

Comment: Hi, I tried with this: `new File( path) << mockRequest.rawRequestData` but i still to have the same error

Comment: Are you sure rawRequestData contains the bytes of a gzip file?

Comment: I have replaced `new File( path) << mockRequest.rawRequestData` by `new File( path) << mockRequest.getRequestContent()` and check if the ccontent format is gzip with the following code: `GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(mockRequest.getRequestContent().getBytes()))` and no exception was logged. So the content saved in the file are **now** in gzip. However, when I try to decompress (manually) I have the following message : Checksum error in name_file.gz.